# Efficiency penalty of initializing a struct/class within a loop

Tags: c++, performance, class, loops, struct

I've done my best to find an answer to this with no luck. Also, I've tested it and don't see any difference whatsoever in an optimized release build (there is a difference in debug)... still, I can't imagine why there is no difference, or how the optimizer is able to remove the penalty, and maybe someone knows what is happening internally.

If I create new instances of a simple class/struct within a loop, is there any penalty in efficiency for creating the class/struct on every loop iteration?

i.e.

```
struct mystruct
{
    inline mystruct(const double &initial) : _myvalue(initial) {}
    double myvalue;
}
```

why does...

```
for(int i=0; i<big_int; ++i)
{
    mystruct a = mystruct(1.1)
}
```

take the same amount of real time as

```
for(int i=0; i<big_int; ++i)
{
    double s = 1.1
}
```

?? Shouldn't there be some time required for the constructor/initialization?

Comment: For how long did you iterate the loop? Sometimes differences are miniscule

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with a long double time accumulation and was able to get a time to accumulate, but weirdly the second option took more time in release! Maybe this is a micro optimisation situation, but I really thought option 1 would be noticeably slower.

Comment: Why don't you disassemble the code? Output the assembly code using a compiler and a flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy-peasy work for a modern optimizer to handle.

As a programmer you might look at that constructor and struct and think it has to cost something. *"The constructor code involves branching, passing arguments through registers/stack, popping from the stack, etc. The struct is a user-defined type, it must add more data somewhere. There's aliasing/indirection overhead for the const reference, etc."*

Except the optimizer then has a go at your code, and it notices that the `struct` has no virtual functions, it has no objects that require a non-trivial constructor. The whole thing fits into a general-purpose register. And then it notices that your constructor is doing little more than assigning one variable to another. And it'll probably even notice that you're just calling it with a literal constant, which translates to a single move/store instruction to a register which doesn't even require any additional memory beyond the instruction.

It's all very magical, and compilers are sophisticated beasts, but they usually do this in multiple passes, and from your original code to intermediate representations, and from intermediate representations to machine code. To really appreciate and understand what they do, it's worth having a peek at the disassembly from time to time.

It's worth noting that C++ has been around for decades. As a successor to C, it originally was pushed mostly as an object-oriented language with hot concepts like encapsulation and information hiding. To promote a language where people start replacing public data members and manual initialization/destruction and things like that for simple accessor functions, constructors, destructors, it would have been very difficult to popularize the language if there was a measurable overhead in even a simple function call. So as magical as this all sounds, C++ optimizers have been doing this now for decades, squashing all that overhead you add to make things easier to maintain down to the same assembly as something which wouldn't be so easy to maintain.

So it's generally worth thinking of things like function calls and small structures as being basically free, since if it's worth inlining and squashing away all the overhead to zilch, optimizers will generally do it. Exceptions arise with indirect function calls: virtual methods, calls through function pointers, etc. But the code you posted is easy stuff for a modern optimizer to squash down.

Comment: +1: But note that it's not that compilers *on the whole* are particlularly complicated or magical, but that modern C++ compilers in particular are some of the most highly sophisticated and highly optimising of any language, owing to the length of time for which C++ has been extremely popular, and the intended use of C++ as a low-level, high-performance language.

Comment: @Mankarse I might be a bit biased as someone studying compiler design as of late and being dazzled by the sophisticated techniques even for topics like register allocation at the language-agnostic IR level. I kinda consider all the modern compilers of any language to be somewhat magical, though perhaps especially C++.

Comment: great answer. I tend to be tentative about how and where I initialize memory (or don't in this case).

Answer (score 3):

C++ philosophy is that you should not "pay" (in CPU cycles or in memory bytes) for anything that you do not use. The `struct` in your example is nothing more than a `double` with a constructor tied to it. Moreover, the constructor can be inlined, bringing the overhead all the way down to zero.

If your `struct` had other parts to initialize, such as other fields or a table of virtual functions, there would be some overhead. The way your example is set up, however, the compiler can optimize out the constructor, producing an assembly output that boils down to a single assignment of a `double`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to stackoverflow so can't upvote you. I tried. See my response to @Mankarse, I think you're both answering my question. I want a struct that is fully minimal under one compiler setting, and more complex under another, without a penalty in the minimal case. It seems there is none. Thanks. I guess I'm still a little skeptical of the c++ mantra, and to what level it reaches.

Comment: @joshua Where it's worth being skeptical most is memory-related if you get micro-level but want real, measurable gains. It's worth paying attention to the size and alignment of things, and you might want to check the sizeof(T) from time to time. It's also worth having more contiguuos data for spatial locality, and using teeny std::vectors everywhere can degrade that performance (yet in the same way you would in C if you used dynamic arrays all over the place). That's if you really want to still scrape metal with C++ and get down and dirty with custom allocators and so forth.

Comment: @joshua The nice thing about C++ is that if you really have those low-level memory efficiency needs, you can still wrap it into something safe and convenient to use, and that wrapper will generally cost nothing. I'm more of a C coder but I appreciate C++ for the safety it adds back on top of my raw C code without making it slower.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your loops do anything. Dead code may be removed. Furthermore, there is no representational difference between a `struct` containing a single `double` and a primitive `double`. The compier should be able to easily "see through" an inline constructor. C++ relies on optimisations of these things to allow its abstractions to compete with hand-written versions.

There is no reason for the performance to be different, and if it were, I would consider it a bug (up to debug builds, where debug information could change the performance cost).

Comment: Yeah, I tried to simplify them for this post. I added some operations within the loops and made sure the values were utilized elsewhere so they were not optimized away, but always with the same number of operations outside of the general initialization. But, you may have answered my question anyway... Is there really no difference between a struct containing a double and a primitive double? Even if that struct has an initializer and, potentially other functions?

Comment: @joshua: The C++ standard includes the "as if" rule; meaning that an implementation need only follow the observable semantics of some code, rather than using any implementation in particular. In all C++ implementations that I know of, member functions are essentially identical to free-functions that take a pointer to their member-object as a (hidden) first parameter. ...

Comment: The presence or absence of a function has essentially no runtime cost; in particluar, the inclusion of a function into a `class` will have no effect on the size of objects of that class, or on code that does not actually use those functions. (Of course this changes when virtual functions are used). Furthermore, trivial functions that are visible at their point of use (like the constructor in your example) are almost always inlined.

Comment: For example, it is very likely that: `sizeof (double) == sizeof (mystruct)`. Also see how (for the particular compiler implementation in [this link](https://goo.gl/dqrDje)), both of your code snippets are transformed to exactly the same assembly output (an empty function, i.e. literally no code).

Comment: Awesome link. Thanks. I tried a (barely) more complicated form and still no difference. Very helpful. [link](https://goo.gl/ChhRGo)

Answer (score 1):

These quotes from the C++ Standard may help to understand what optimization is permitted:

> The semantic descriptions in this International Standard define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the **observable behavior** of the abstract machine as explained below.

and also:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.
>
> These collectively are referred to as the observable behavior of the program.

To summarize: the compiler can generate whatever executable it likes so long as that executable performs the same I/O and access to volatile variables as the unoptimized version would.  In particular, there are no requirements about timing or memory allocation.

---

In your code sample, the entire thing could be optimized out as it produces no observable behaviour. However, real-world compilers sometimes decide to leave in things that could be optimized out, if they think the programmer really wanted those operations to happen for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

@Ikes answer is exactly what I was getting at. However, If you are curious about this question, I very much recommend reading answers of @dasblinkenlight, @Mankarse, and @Matt McNabb and the discussions below them, which get at the details of the situation. Thanks all.